# How to check if a path leads outside of a directory in c?

Tags: c, linux, bash, path, directory

I'm trying to check if a path leads to 'upper' than the current directory.
Example :

I'm inside `"./"`

Let's say the current directory contains a folder named "folder"

I want to check if `cd "./folder/../../"` will lead me outside of "./".
In this case, it would answer me True.

This is to bound my program to its execution folder (i want it to execute ls but never outside).

Comment: There is no standard function for this in C. You need to count number of "../" and number of "text/" and based on those counts, you should find out whether path is outside directory.

Comment: You may want to look at how [readlink implements the `-f` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24293/converting-relative-path-to-absolute-path-without-symbolic-link).

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/canonicalize.c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX.1-2001 defines [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html):

> ```
> #include <limits.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> char *realpath(const char *path, char *resolved_path);
> ```
>
> `realpath()`  expands  all  symbolic  links and resolves references to `/./`, `/../` and extra `'/'` characters in the null-terminated string named by path to produce a canonicalized absolute pathname.  The resulting pathname is stored as a null-terminated string, up to a maximum of `PATH_MAX` bytes, in the buffer pointed to by `resolved_path`.  The resulting path will have no symbolic link,  `/./`  or  `/../` components.

You could compare the canonicalized path to the current directory and see if the former is a descendant of the latter.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_inside(const char *parent, const char *child) {
    char *abs_parent = realpath(parent, NULL);
    if (!abs_parent) { perror(parent); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    char *abs_child  = realpath(child,  NULL);
    if (!abs_child)  { perror(child);  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    size_t parent_len = strlen(abs_parent);
    size_t child_len  = strlen(abs_child);

    bool result = strncmp(abs_parent, abs_child, parent_len) == 0 &&
        (child_len == parent_len || abs_child[parent_len] == '/');

    free(abs_parent);
    free(abs_child);

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <parent> <child>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", is_inside(argv[1], argv[2]) ? "yes" : "no");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this only works if the paths exist.

Comment: Note that `realpath()`  won't work should `path` refer to non-existent path objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of components that matched "..", ".", :

```
for (p = strtok(path, "/"); p; p = strtok(NULL, "/")) {
        if (strcmp(p, "..") == 0) {
                counters[Back]++;
        } else if (strcmp(p, ".") == 0) {
                counters[Self]++;
        } else if (*p) {  /* ignore /// runs */
                counters[Forw]++;
        }
        escaped |= (counters[Back] > counters[Forw]);
}
```

*Escaped* captures whether the path attempted to escape from the tree under the current working directory.   It is probably worthwhile special casing a leading "/" as an escape.

There are other approaches which decode the absolute pathspace, but may lead to over-reach (imho, a common systems failure mode).  I, in the role of owner, might want your program to accept pathnames which escape your namespace, at least in a limited fashion.  Symlinks work well for this, do not require special adminstrative control, etc...   If your program prevents this sort of configuration, then its utility is diminished.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

---

Get the current full path (`pwd`)
cd to the new path
get the new full path
if new full path starts with old full path, it's in*

- you might need to scan for the possibility of symlinks &c, but if that's a non-issue this should handle it.

Haven't done `C` in a while, but here's a quick hack of the same logic in `bash`

```
$: pwd
/tmp/sandbox
$: cur=$(pwd)
$: cd ./folder/../../
$: pwd
/tmp
$: pwd|grep "^$cur" && echo in || echo out
out

$: cd -
/tmp/sandbox
$: pwd|grep "^$cur" && echo in || echo out
/tmp/sandbox
in

$: cd ./folder/
$: pwd|grep "^$cur" && echo in || echo out
/tmp/sandbox/folder
in
```